# Find last row has stopped working on spilled ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that I have been using for years in some form or other.  Many people will recognise that it returns a reference to the last populated cell on a worksheet.

Excel asked me to apply an update this morning (not sure if that's relevant), but since then it's not returning the last cell in a spilled range.  Entering `=SEQUENCE(8)` on a blank sheet returns $A$1 rather than $A$8.

Please, someone tell me I'm not losing it.... this should return the last cell in a spilled range shouldn't it?  If it shouldn't then I've no idea how my reports have been running for the last few years.

```
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        With wrkSht
            lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
            lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        End With
        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1
        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Try with 3. `LookIn:=xlValues`. Keep in mind that you can get the last cell with e.g. `With Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion: Debug.Print .Cells(.Cells.Count).Address: End With`.

Comment: Please, try `lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row`...

Comment: `xlValues` of course.  Thankyou @VBasic2008.  Should've realised that, but nursing a hangover today. :)